# I want to count how many cards can I print in one page

Tags: excel, printing

how are you ?

I want way to count number of cards that I can print in one page

I have different page size , and also I have different cards size

I want a way that I can give page size and then card size and number of the crads then he will give me the number of pages that I need

I tried to do it in Excel but the problem it will cut the cards and distribute them in a page so I can't get the real number of pages

for example, if I have an A3 page and I want to print business cards on it with size 9*5.3
the page will fit for 30 business cards only but Excel will make it fit for 33 , the additional 3 will cut it and distributed it on the remaining area of the page

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a heuristic optimization problem, so Excel may not be best suited to finding a solution.

That being said, if you *are* going to use Excel, try the Solver add-in - it is designed for this kind of task. Unfortunately, making a sample solution will probably take a lot more detail regarding you input data. The MS tutorials will walk you setting it up, though:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/define-and-solve-a-problem-by-using-solver-5d1a388f-079d-43ac-a7eb-f63e45925040

[This 'storage space vs boxes' example](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/2345556/excel-solver-optimized-shelf-space) is not exactly the same problem you have, but maybe it will help.